# What is the equivalent of v4sf and __attribute__ in Visual Studio C++?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, sse, intrinsics

```
typedef float v4sf __attribute__ ((mode(V4SF)));
```

This is in GCC. Anyone knows the equivalence syntax?

VS 2010 will show `__attribute__` has no storage class of this type, and mode is not defined.

I searched on the Internet and it said

> Equivalent to `__attribute__( aligned( size ) )` in GCC
>
> It is helpful
> for former unix developers or people writing code that works on
> multiple platforms that in GCC you achieve the same results using
> **attribute**( aligned( ... ) )
>
> See here for more information:
> http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Type-Attributes.html#Type-Attributes

The full GCC code is here:  http://pastebin.com/bKkTTmH1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're looking for the alignment directive in VC++ it's `__declspec(align(16))`. (or whatever you want the alignment to be)

And example usage is this:

```
__declspec(align(16)) float x[] = {1.,2.,3.,4.};
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65.aspx

Note that both `attribute` (in GCC) and `__declspec` (in VC++) are compiler-specific extensions.

**EDIT :**

Now that I take a second look at the code, it's gonna take more work than just replacing the `__attribute__` line with the VC++ equivalent to get it to compile in VC++.

VC++ doesn't have any if these macros/functions that you are using:

- `__builtin_ia32_xorps`
- `__builtin_ia32_loadups`
- `__builtin_ia32_mulps`
- `__builtin_ia32_addps`
- `__builtin_ia32_storeups`

You're better off just replacing all of those with [SSE intrinsics](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html) - which will work on both GCC and VC++.

---

Here's the code converted to intrinsics:

```
float *mv_mult(float mat[SIZE][SIZE], float vec[SIZE]) {
    static float ret[SIZE];
    float temp[4];
    int i, j;
    __m128 m, v, r;

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        r = _mm_xor_ps(r, r);

        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j += 4) {
            m = _mm_loadu_ps(&mat[i][j]);
            v = _mm_loadu_ps(&vec[j]);
            v = _mm_mul_ps(m, v);
            r = _mm_add_ps(r, v);
        }

        _mm_storeu_ps(temp, r);
        ret[i] = temp[0] + temp[1] + temp[2] + temp[3];
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Hi again ! :)  Yeah. I noticed that. I would have to convert from v4sf to m128 types... Let me try :) Thanks. SSE is new to me. Ha.

Comment: It doesn't look that hard actually. I've edited my answer with the converted code. However, I want to point out that unaligned accesses could kill your performance. So you might want to consider modifying the algorithm to align the data.

Comment: Woo. Thank you very much. I created a union __m128 to align data. Thanks Mysticial for the unaligned one.

Answer (score 1):

V4SF and friends have to do with GCC "vector extensions":

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html#Vector%20Extensions

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/X86-Built-in-Functions.html

I'm not sure how much - if any of this stuff - is supported in MSVS/MSVC.  Here are a few links:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/sseintro.aspx?msg=643444

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0dh78ez%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01fth20w.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Yes. Now the big problem is converting between m128 and v4sf since the operations require to use m128 types. Thanks.