# Error expected ';' while building solution in cuda c

Tags: cuda, aes

I am trying to do encryption decryption in cuda using c. I downloaded the code, but while but while building solution. It gives error expected ';' I commented as //HERE where the error in the code. I tried but cant find solution. My downloaded code looks like.

```
uint32_t sw(uint32_t word)
{
    union {
        uint32_t word;
        uint8_t bytes[4];
    } subWord  __attribute__ ((aligned));//HERE
    subWord.word = word;

    subWord.bytes[3] = s_h[subWord.bytes[3]];
    subWord.bytes[2] = s_h[subWord.bytes[2]];
    subWord.bytes[1] = s_h[subWord.bytes[1]];
    subWord.bytes[0] = s_h[subWord.bytes[0]];

    return subWord.word;
}
```

and the error is like

```
    C:/Users/pcw/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/MyCudaApp        /MyCudaApp/TEST AES.cu(157): error : expected a ";"
  1>C:/Users/pcw/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/MyCudaApp/MyCudaApp/TEST AES.cu(175): error : expected a ";"
  1>C:/Users/pcw/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/MyCudaApp/MyCudaApp/TEST AES.cu(179): error : expected a ";"
  1>C:/Users/pcw/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/MyCudaApp/MyCudaApp/TEST AES.cu(218): error : expected a ";"
```

Comment: Remove the `#include <cuda_runtime.h>`, rename the file to have a `.cu` extension and compile again, using `nvcc`.

Comment: And it's `__align__(16)` (or whatever alignment you are after) in CUDA.

Comment: If you have a syntax error in a union, why did you feel it is necessary to post 400 lines of code?

Answer (score 1):

The code you are trying to compile contains [gcc specific variable attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html#Common-Variable-Attributes), which are not supported by the Microsoft C++ compiler.

To compile this you will need to replace `__attribute__` with something that Visual Studio understands. You can see a discussion of this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8290177/681865).